# microsecond to readable datetime in xsl

Tags: datetime, xslt-1.0, datetime-format

I want to transform the Date and Time in an xml file which is in "microsecond" to a human readable format like (2016-10-14) using XSLT 1.0 stylesheet transformation, this is the xml content below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<News DateTime="636120534151823750" Id="5241">
</News>
```

Many thanks,

Comment: Noway is that a microsecond unixtimestamp. stripping off the last 6 digits to get seconds gives you Nov 9th, 22127, which is wee bit into the future... So exactly WHAT does that number represent? Where does it come from?

Comment: @Marc B : indeed, the OP's 18-digit number seems to come from DateTime.Now.Ticks, as shown here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/M6MLsK

Comment: OP : your date timestamp shown in your question isn't expressed in "microseconds" (and since when would it be anyway? You ought to mention it somehow); it seems to be the result of DateTime.Ticks instead, the unit of which is a tenth of a microsecond (10 millions of those in a second) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MarcB:  It comes from a news agency, they send the date and time in this format. according to what they say its starting from 1970 until today in the form of Ticks.

Comment: @YSharp: You are right as I have checked again with the source they told me that its in ticks.

Comment: then this is relevant: `The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 (0:00:00 UTC on January 1, 0001, in the Gregorian calendar),` you'd need a helluva lot of math to convert that into a unix timestamp, which is what xslt will be using for date/time stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="News">
    <dateTime>
        <xsl:call-template name="datetime.ticks-to-datetime">
            <xsl:with-param name="datetime.ticks" select="@DateTime" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </dateTime>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="datetime.ticks-to-datetime">
    <xsl:param name="datetime.ticks"/>

    <xsl:variable name="JDN" select="floor($datetime.ticks div 864000000000) + 1721426" />
    <xsl:variable name="rem-ticks" select="$datetime.ticks mod 864000000000"/>

    <xsl:variable name="f" select="$JDN + 1401 + floor((floor((4 * $JDN + 274277) div 146097) * 3) div 4) - 38"/>
    <xsl:variable name="e" select="4*$f + 3"/>
    <xsl:variable name="g" select="floor(($e mod 1461) div 4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="h" select="5*$g + 2"/>

    <xsl:variable name="d" select="floor(($h mod 153) div 5 ) + 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="(floor($h div 153) + 2) mod 12 + 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="floor($e div 1461) - 4716 + floor((14 - $m) div 12)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="H" select="floor($rem-ticks div 36000000000)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="M" select="floor($rem-ticks mod 36000000000 div 600000000)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="S" select="$rem-ticks mod 600000000 div 10000000"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($y, '0000')" />    
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($m, '-00')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($d, '-00')"/>   

    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($H, ' 00')" />    
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($M, ':00')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($S, ':00')"/>   
</xsl:template>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<dateTime>2016-10-14 14:50:15</dateTime>
```

Comment: thank you so much that solved my problem, but would it be possible to calculate the time also in the same way?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the exact result you want?

Comment: the solution you have provided is the exactly what I want, but for my future reference I would like to know how to get the time also like for example: 
2016-10-17 12:30:00 

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @JohnMiller See the edit to my post. Note also the correction to the `JDN` var calculation.

Comment: Thank you very much that was really helpful.